# Parallel Programming stuck on 4th instance of Concurrency::create_task call for serial devices

Tags: serial-port, raspberry-pi3, c++-cx

I am currently developing a program where Raspberry Pi 3 will read contents sent by 4 Arduino (USB) devices through serial communication every 100ms. The UI gets stuck on the fourth call (serialDeviceIndex = 3) of Concurrency::create_task but if there are only 3 Arduino devices, the problem is not happening and the thread execution continues to the .then lambda body. Can you help me pin point what is the problem? Here's the function called when the `connect` button from the xaml devices is pressed.

```
void MainPage::comPortInput_Click(Object^ sender, RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{   
m_timer->Start();
auto selectionIndex = ConnectDevices->SelectedIndex;

if (selectionIndex < 0)
{
    status->Text = "Select a device and connect";
    return;
}

auto selectedItems = ConnectDevices->SelectedItems;

for (unsigned serialDeviceIndex = 0; serialDeviceIndex < selectedItems->Size; serialDeviceIndex++)
{
        Device ^device = static_cast<Device ^>(selectedItems->GetAt(serialDeviceIndex));
        textBox->Text = textBox->Text + "\n<START>:" + device->Id->ToString() + "<END>";
        Windows::Devices::SerialCommunication::SerialDevice ^serial_device;
        Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation ^entry = device->DeviceInfo;

        auto childTokenSource = Concurrency::cancellation_token_source::create_linked_source(cancellationTokenSource->get_token());

        auto childToken = childTokenSource.get_token();

        Concurrency::create_task(
            Windows::Devices::SerialCommunication::SerialDevice::FromIdAsync(entry->Id), childToken)
            .then([this, serialDeviceIndex](Windows::Devices::SerialCommunication::SerialDevice ^serial_device)
        {
            _serialPort = serial_device;
            Platform::String ^deviceString1 = _serialPort->ToString();
            // Disable the 'Connect' button 
            //comPortInput->IsEnabled = false;
            Windows::Foundation::TimeSpan _timeOut;
            _timeOut.Duration = 100000L; //100000 works with delay(200)

            // Configure serial settings
            _serialPort->WriteTimeout = _timeOut;

            _serialPort->ReadTimeout = _timeOut;
            _serialPort->BaudRate = 9600;
            _serialPort->Parity = Windows::Devices::SerialCommunication::SerialParity::None;
            _serialPort->StopBits = Windows::Devices::SerialCommunication::SerialStopBitCount::One;
            _serialPort->DataBits = 8;
            _serialPort->Handshake = Windows::Devices::SerialCommunication::SerialHandshake::None;

            _dataReaderObject = ref new Windows::Storage::Streams::DataReader(_serialPort->InputStream);
            _dataReaderObject->InputStreamOptions = Windows::Storage::Streams::InputStreamOptions::Partial;

            _dataReaderObjects.Append(_dataReaderObject);
            _serialPorts.Append(_serialPort);
            int serialPortsSize = _serialPorts.Size;
            Listen(_serialPorts.GetAt(serialDeviceIndex), _dataReaderObject, serialDeviceIndex);
        });
    Sleep(5);
}
```

}

EDIT:

Okay, I simplified now the code to JUST this one

```
for (unsigned serialDeviceIndex = 0; serialDeviceIndex < selectedItems->Size; serialDeviceIndex++){
    Device ^device = static_cast<Device ^>(selectedItems->GetAt(serialDeviceIndex));
    textBox->Text = textBox->Text + "\n<START>:" + device->Id->ToString() + "<END>";
    Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation ^entry = device->DeviceInfo;
    auto it = Concurrency::create_task(Windows::Devices::SerialCommunication::SerialDevice::FromIdAsync(entry->Id));

    while (!it.is_done())
        textBoxStatus->Text = "processing" + deviceIndex.ToString();

    it.get();
}
```

FYI, this code runs normally fine in my pc. no errors. When I try to run this in my RaspberryPi3 under Windows IoT the program hungs up at the fourth time I try to get the device using `it.get()`

Comment: 4 is a magic number on a midget board with a quad processor.  That Listen() call looks awfully suspicious.  Comment it out, if it now works then you  know you posted the wrong code.

Comment: @HansPassant I already added the `Listen` method implementation. I hope it could give you some hints?

Comment: You'll have to throw this away, it can never work correctly.  it is a threading race bug waiting to happen, the m_vectorStrings[] content will be overwritten randomly.  Particularly so when the UI gets slow because it has too many devices to support.  Focus first on writing the code to actually receive the full response, not just the one or two bytes you get now.  Then use, say, as task continuation to update the UI.  And consider that updating the UI isn't all that useful anyway, nobody can read that fast.

Comment: @Gibs I don't see any reason for this code to work in case of 3 and fail in case of 4. Maybe it is indeed something connected with quad processor. How about limiting recusion on `Listen` to 100-200 iterations on 4th tread and see what happens whenever it quits - does UI get unblocked?

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, yeah I noticed that the output strings are mixed up. I am not sure what thread you're referring to but I checked the parallel stacks and they are just using one thread

Comment: You always have two threads involved, one that executes the task and the UI thread.  They are not synchronized in any way right now.

Comment: @HansPassant Just updated the code again. Getting the result makes the device hang up on the fourth time i get the returned `SerialDevice` object. No other methods are called inside the four loop.