# What is the SerialPort Class equivalent from .Net to UWP C++ in visual studio?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio

Sorry, I think this problem is because I am new to Visual Studio. I just wanted to ask how I can use a SerialPort Class like one from .Net Framework to my UWP app in visual studio? I don't have idea what namespace I can place on this statement `using namespace Windows:: *Library_For_SerialPort*`. I know there's a SerialDevice but I wanted to implement the objects on my own.

Comment: Is .net even accessible in winrt?

Comment: I don't know too. Sorry I don't have any idea

Comment: What I wanted to express with my comment is that I believe the answer is simply: You can't ( without kids off hackery). But I might be wrong.

Comment: I see, I am changing the post title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your have answer in your post: `SerialDevice`. Naming is different, but public interfaces look similar, with such exception that `SerialDevice` uses only streams to read/write. You can open/close ports/devices, configure it. Which functions / attributes do you miss here? If you really want your own class you should wrap it around `SerialDevice`. Also, I don't think you can use SerialPort directly in UWP without some hacking.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @R2RT I asked this question because no one could help me from this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662620/parallel-programming-stuck-on-4th-instance-of-concurrencycreate-task-call-for?noredirect=1#comment78375706_45662620